# File::delete($image_path) no esta funcionando

Tags: laravel-8

**La imagen que debería eliminarse no se elimina.**

1. Tengo un **evento** cuando se elimina un modelo Profile.

```
    /**
     * Handle the post "deleting" event.
     */
    public function deleting(Profile $profile)
    {
        $this->deleteProfilePhoto($profile);
    }
```

1.1 Método de eliminación de imagen (**ojo**: este código funciona en mi controlador cuando por ejemplo actualizo y quiero eliminar la imagen anterior)

```
    /**
     * Delete profile photo.
     */
    private function deleteProfilePhoto(Profile $profile) {
        $image_path = $profile->photo;
        if(! str_contains($image_path, 'default') &&
            File::exists($image_path) ) {
            File::delete($image_path);
            $profile->photo = null;
        }
    }
```

2. Tengo un **schedule** con la siguiente **tarea** en *App\Console\Commands*

```
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Profile::whereNull('user_id')->get()->each(function($profile) {
            $profile->delete();
        });
    }
```

3. Evento añadido en App\Console\Kernel.php

```
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('remove:profile')->daily();
    }
```

El schedule lo ejecuto con el comando **php artisan schedule:test**

No sé que estoy haciendo mal, agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: No estoy seguro de si al usar comandos se ejecutan los observers. Antes de nada, recarga la configuración, `php artisan config:clear`, luego añade trazados (logs) en las partes importantes, 
p.e. en tus bloques 2 y 3: `logger('deleteing ' . $profile->id); $profile->delete();` 
`logger('@schedule ' ); $schedule->command('remove:profile')->daily();`

Comment: He ejecutado el comando **php artisan config:clear** y he impreso mensajes en mi archivo log, los métodos se están llamando bien, he eliminado la sentencia if de mi método deleteProfilePhoto() dejando solo la línea  **File::delete($image_path);** si imprimo la ruta de imagen es tal cual la que existe en el directorio storage que apunta a la imagen ha ser eliminida. Parece que File::delete() no esta funcionando he revisado la importación y es la correcta use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; ¿Sabes que pueda ser?

Answer (score 0):

**Solución**

Esto funciona en mi controlador **File::delete($image_path)** pero en este caso
File no estaba buscando desde la ruta del directorio público, tuve que pasar la url a **public_path()** para que funcionara.

Finalmente esto funcionó:

```
File::delete(public_path($image_path))
```